# How can I give a thickness to this iframe 3D transformed with CSS?

Tags: css

This is my code:

```js
scaleIframe();

window.onresize = scaleIframe;

function scaleIframe() {
  var scale = window.innerWidth * 0.50 / 1440;
  document.getElementById('myIframe').style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
}
```

```css
.media_item {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.iframe-container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: calc(50vw / 1.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: perspective(100vw) rotateY(30deg);
}

#myIframe {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="media_item">
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" width="1440" height="800"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make the iframe look like a plate with a thickness. So it shouldn't be flat as it is now. How can this be done?

Comment: What do you want to achieve specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `clip-path` like I am doing here: https://css-tip.com/image-3d-effect/ and here is a related article to explain the `clip-path`: https://dev.to/afif/3d-image-with-one-element-1c87

```js
scaleIframe();

window.onresize = scaleIframe;

function scaleIframe() {
  var scale = window.innerWidth * 0.50 / 1440;
  document.getElementById('myIframe').style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
}
```

```css
.media_item {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.iframe-container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: calc(50vw / 1.8);
  transform: perspective(100vw) rotateY(30deg);
  clip-path: polygon(0 5px, 10px 0,100% 0,100% 100%,10px 100%,0 calc(100% - 5px));
   
}
.iframe-container:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  inset: 0 auto 0 0;
  width: 10px;
  background: #0005
}

#myIframe {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="media_item">
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" width="1440" height="800"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a little additional question: Right now, the plate is not centered perfectly in the ".media_item". Do I have this to adjust manually with margin, or is there another way to center it?